# UIDatePicker getting GTM value

Tags: iphone, swift, swift2

I need to sent a date with a timezone value in GTM. How can you get this from UIDatePicker?

I need the following format:

```
"02/Jan/2006:15:04:05 -0700
```

I have tried this in swift:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy:HH:mm"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
let strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(myDatePicker.date)
self.selectedDate.text = strDate
```

and also this:

```
self.myDatePicker.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
```

Comment: are you sure about the use of ```GTM```and ```GMT```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the letter for the timezone is `z`for the name of the timezone and `Z`for the difference to GMT if this is what you are asking for

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z"
```

http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: did you give it a try?

Comment: That is so right. Thank you very much!! Had a label covering the value :-|